# Django app on Heroku deletes objects after some time

Tags: python, django, heroku, sqlite

I've written a simple Django Q&A forum app and deployed it on Heroku. The local version of the site works fine. However, the production version does not store the questions, answers etc. for more than a few hours.

I decided to stick with sqlite3 that comes with Django. I don't expect a lot of traffic to the site so I decided it would be worth it to keep the development database for now.

site: http://immense-plateau-35286.herokuapp.com

I've tried a few solutions from the DB setup page on Heroku, but have not had any success so far.

Any idea what this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Anything you write to it will be lost anytime your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting). Since SQLite stores its data in a file on the filesystem it isn't a good choice on Heroku.

Instead, consider using one of the [many client-server data stores](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) that Heroku supports. [Its PostgreSQL offering](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) works reasonably well.