# How to not override images folder when 'git push heroku'?

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, express, heroku

I tried to find solution for hours but I don't even know how to call it. I've made a node.JS app, using 'Heroku' to deploy and 'MLab' for MongoDB.

Every user can upload image, and the image url ('~/img/{user_id}.jpg') stores in mongoDB, the name of the image is the id of the user.

```
user.imgUrl = __dirname+'/../public/img/users_avatars/'+user.id+'.jpg';
```

and show the image on 'ejs' page:

```
<img src="<%=user.imgUrl%>" alt="avatar">
```

But, everytime I push to Heroku (everytime I update the code) the "img" folder dissappear (the commit override it).

```
git add .
git commit -m "some_message"
git push heroku
```

I made .gitignore file

```
node_modules/
/public/img/
```

But it does'nt seem to work, the images are'nt shown.

Can I push my changes to Heroku somehow and keep the 'img' folder without any change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django app on Heroku deletes objects after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745393/django-app-on-heroku-deletes-objects-after-some-time)

Comment: Each time you push to Heroku it Redeploys the app (reinstantiates it).  Heroku IS NOT a hosting service; in the traditional sense.  @TGrif has provided you a good approach.  The other alternative is to store the images using a service like AWS S3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no persistent storage on *heroku*, so no, you can't.

One thing you can do, on the other hand, is to store your images on MongoDB since you have a mLab database.
For example, you could use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to store your raw image files, so that they persist independently of your *heroku* code application.