# ProgrammingError at /sign-up/

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-forms, heroku-cli

i recently deplolyed my todoapp on heroku and it works just fine, at least until i try creating an account then it prompts me with this error:

relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username

i'm so confused ive tried so many things i.e Heroku app python manage.py makemigrations i get an error something about id not found.

is there anythin i can do?

```
my register view
def register(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
          return redirect('home')
     form = registerform()
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = registerform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)              
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'User does not exist')
        
     return render(request, 'register.html', {'form' : form})


forms.py
class registerform(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: Share the full error traceback

Comment: what does this line `user.username = user.username.lower()` means in the register view i do not think you really need this line?

Comment: You should _never_ have to `makemigrations` on Heroku. However, you _should_ migrate there. I suspect you either haven't, or you have but you're using SQLite.

Comment: im using SQLite3 db

Comment: That's your problem: you can't use SQLite on Heroku.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django app on Heroku deletes objects after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745393/django-app-on-heroku-deletes-objects-after-some-time)