# Django models not being saved to database when updated using Celery and when deployed to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, redis, rabbitmq, celery

So the title is a bit long winded but i think explains my issue pretty well.

I have a Django project that updates models every 60 seconds by scraping currency data from another website using Celery and RabbitMQ. When i run the celery worker locally it works perfectly, however when i deploy to Heroku the models do not update.

When i check the logs (*heroku logs --tail*) It shows that the tasks are running but they aren't updating the database models. I beleive this must be due to some configuration error in my settings.py file but i have tried numerous solutions and nothing has worked. I have also tried changing to use Redis instead and have experienced the same problem (it runs fine in the logs but does not actually update the database).

Here is what i believe to be the relevant code that could be causing the problem.

Settings.py (when using rabbitMQ):

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'rabbitMQ_url_given_from_heroku'
BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "django://")
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = None

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json", "msgpack"]
```

Settings.py (when using Redis):

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'Redis_url_given_from_heroku'
CELERRY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cryptoApi.settings')

app = Celery('cryptoApi')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn cryptoApi.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A cryptoApi worker -l info
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're using SQLite as your database. [That won't work as expected on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47745393/354577).

However, most questions about this present differently: they look like they're working but then data is lost some time later, when new code is deployed or the next day after a dyno restart.

The reason you're not seeing new data *at all* is that [workers run on dedicated dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing#process-model), separate from your `web` dynos, and each dyno will have its own SQLite database. Whatever data you save to one won't be visible on the others.

You'll have to switch to a client-server [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). Heroku's own [Postgres service](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) is usually a good starting point.